# jQuery dry optimization

Tags: jquery, optimization, coding-style, refactoring

Hello i want to ask how can i optimize that code:

```
        $('#infoTrigger0').live('click', function() {
            $('#info0').slideToggle();
        });
        $('#infoTrigger1').live('click', function() {
            $('#info1').slideToggle();
        });
        $('#infoTrigger2').live('click', function() {
            $('#info2').slideToggle();
        });
        $('#infoTrigger3').live('click', function() {
            $('#info3').slideToggle();
        });
        $('#infoTrigger4').live('click', function() {
            $('#info4').slideToggle();
        });
        $('#infoTrigger5').live('click', function() {
            $('#info5').slideToggle();
        });...
```

with loop or something other i have no idea?

Comment: Can you post the HTML this is operating on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', 'elem[id^=infoTrigger]', function() {
      var n = this.id.match(/\d+/g)
      $('#info'+n).slideToggle();
});
```

`live` method is deprecated, you can use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
$('#infoTrigger' +i).live('click', function () {
    $('#info' +i).slideToggle();
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What about ? :

```
for(var i =0;i<6;i++){
  $('#infoTrigger' + i).live('click', function() {
      $('#info' + i).slideToggle();
  });
}
```

I recommend to use `on` over `live` since the last is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

if u make html like this

```
<div class="info" id="info1">
  <div id="info1_sub"></div>
</div>
```

you can apply this

```
 $('.info').live('click', function() {
            var elem="#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_sub";
            $(elem).slideToggle();
        })
```